# Tool to complete words while typing

Tags: software-recommendation, accessibility

I have a friend who is familiar with [etype](http://www.etype.com/). This application helps him by completing and suggesting words while he's typing. Now he is using Ubuntu by my suggestion but he really needs this application on Ubuntu.

Since there is no etype Ubuntu version, is there a similar application for Ubuntu?

What do you suggest guys?

The application should work on:

- Browsers (Firefox, Chromium)
- On word processors like (libreoffice, Openoffice)

Answer (score 6):

Nothing system-wide, it seems, but good news:  OpenOffice Writer has this function built in!  http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Word_Completion

In fact a lot of linux apps have some kind of autocomplete.  The bash shell responds to the TAB key, so do most places in gnome where you enter a filename.  If you're a programmer, then you'll get this (aka intellisense) in most IDEs, such as geany, eclipse, bluefish.  Even the humble gedit has a plugin that does this.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/gedit-python-c-cpp-autocomplete-plugin/gedit-autocomplete/

If you're looking for something system-wide, the only thing I can recommend is AutoKey, which really just expands abbreviations that you've set up in advance.  Not ideal, but it's a start.  Just install it using Ubuntu Software Center.

Hope these tools are enough to attract your friend to this superb OS!

Answer (score 4):

This also isn't system-wide.

If he needs this feature mostly for writing texts, then maybe [Google Scribe](http://scribe.googlelabs.com/) might tickle his fancy. It's still simply in Google Labs, so it might not be *too* impressive yet, but it looks promising.